# Mat cards not the same length

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

So I have an app that displays a couple of diseases. As you can see, the cards aren't the same height and i cant seem to fix it. 
[image: Picture of my app]

here is my Html

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="2%" fxFlexAlign="stretch">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="filterDisease$.next($event.target.value)" placeholder="filter" type="text"
        data-cy="filterInput" [value]="filterDiseaseName" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage" data-cy="appError">
    got an error while loading the disease list: {{ errorMessage }}
  </mat-card>
  <div *ngIf="diseases$ | async as diseases; else loadingOrError">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxFlexAlign="stretch">
      <div class="diseases" *ngFor="let disease of diseases" fxFlex="0 0 calc(25%-0.5%)" fxFlex.xs="100%">
        <app-disease [disease]="disease" data-cy="diseaseCard"></app-disease>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-template #loadingOrError>
    <span *ngIf="errorMessage; else loading"></span>
    <ng-template #loading>
      <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

and here is my css

```css
.diseases {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Can you provide more HTML and CSS so we can see what is happening in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the height of diseases to 100% which is not gonna be fixed if you want to set a fixed height use vh or px instead of % maybe do it like this

```
.diseases {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is flexbox CSS. FYI, this is a CSS question and should have probably been marked as one.

```
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.diseases {
  display: flex; 
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will give you a layout of columns which all have the same height.

Comment: Thanks for the respone! Unfortunately, the only thing this does is spread the cards out more, it doesnt give them the same length

Comment: Can you add a class to the first main wrapper div? If you can, change the first div in my css to the name of the class - I've just noticed that you have two divs in the code which is why its not working yet.

Comment: I did that, but it didnt really change anything

Comment: Please can you update your question to show the rendered html of the cards, I'm not familiar with the syntax you have right now. I'll update my answer with the correct CSS after that

Comment: <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="2%" fxFlexAlign="stretch">
Is this the column? Does this bit repeat for each column or does it wrap the whole area and contain all the columns?

Comment: I fixed it! The problem was in the css of my disease itself (which is a card) not the css in the complete list.

Answer (score -2):

maybe add a refrence to the css file

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

See if that solves it.

And also set a size in units like px, cm, or a picas(pc) perhaps.

Comment: It's quite clear he has a CSS file linked as you can see the page is styled from his screenshot

Comment: hmm, I'm actually a python person, my brother does the front-end. I try to understand it but I don't mostly, So I guess I will stick to my field next time, thanks.